# Convert a JavaPairRDD into list without collect()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, groovy

My spark job crashes at collect() statement with below error. 
emphasized textBelow is the error I receive.

```
Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor13.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:239)
    at org.oclc.wcsync.hadoop.serverdsl.record.InputRecord.<init>(InputRecord.groovy:50)
    at org.oclc.wcsync.hadoop.serverdsl.record.InputRecordConstructorAccess.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.twitter.chill.Instantiators$$anonfun$reflectAsm$1.apply(KryoBase.scala:141)
    at com.twitter.chill.Instantiators$$anon$1.newInstance(KryoBase.scala:125)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstance(Kryo.java:1090)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.create(FieldSerializer.java:570)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:546)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
    at com.twitter.chill.Tuple1Serializer.read(TupleSerializers.scala:30)
    at com.twitter.chill.Tuple1Serializer.read(TupleSerializers.scala:23)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream.readValue(Serializer.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter$SpillReader.org$apache$spark$util$collection$ExternalSorter$SpillReader$$readNextItem(ExternalSorter.scala:558)
18/08/29 15:20:06 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
18/08/29 15:20:06 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

This is the code :

```
JavaRDD<File> myRecords = sc.parallelize(mapper.myFunction(records.collect())).cache()
```

myFunction uses a list of "records" and  iterate through them . So I am using records.collect() and passing it into  "myFunction" .But collect() statement brings all data to driver and causes this error.I am looking for any alternate that I can use to avoid this error. I know count can be used instead of collect but I need a list here  .

```
  List myFunction(List<scala.Tuple2<String, Tuple1<List<Record>>>> data) {
        List<File> list = []

        // Iterate through the List of Tuple2 instance


        list
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated .

Comment: i am still stuck with this issue. The similar question which was answered says to use foreach. But where should I use foreach, is it in the function(myFunction) .

Comment: @eliasah anyhelp?

Comment: There might be an alternative solution to make your app run but with the question’s current state, it’s merely salvageable.

Comment: This is one of the reason we always ask for an MVCE when seeking for debugging.

Comment: @eliasah , I am trying to use foreach on a JavaPairRDD , but how do we iterate a JavaPairRDD in groovy using foreach ?

Comment: What kind of actions do you want to perform with foreach ? Something that you can’t perform with a map/reduce or an aggregator. I have this feeling that you might be tackling your problem from the wrong angle.